# How to change the background color of a button when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am starting on angular and I am developing with my internship colleagues a catalog application, here is my problem:

I have these little buttons like this in the menu:

[btn menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHHms.png)

[image]

and I want that when I click on one of its buttons, its background will be colored in orange, like this one for example:

[btn color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k326Q.png)

[image]

[picture acceuil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFSGw.png)

[image]

as you can see here i clicked on the home button and it brought me back to the home page and the "home" button its background is well colored in orange.

Now I want that when I click on one of the 3 buttons that I displayed above their background is colored in orange and the other button which was selected in front of its background is colored in black, so on ...

here is the code of my component.html:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown activ"><a class="dropdown-toggle" [routerLink]="['home']" class="active" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Accueil </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search"></i> recherche <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['nonRelationEntity']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> entités sans relations</a></li>
        </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-book"></i> catalogue <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['entity']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> entité</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['relation']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> relation</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['gestionCatalogue']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> gestion catalogue</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exchange-alt"></i> mapping <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['profileMapping']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> mapping des profiles</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['profile']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> profile</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['scopeMapping']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> mapping des scopes</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['scope']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> scope</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li *ngIf="edit" class="element"><a [routerLink]="['import']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-alt-circle-up  "></i> import</a></li>
        <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['export']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-alt-circle-down  "></i> export</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cogs"></i> administration <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['catalog']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> catalogue</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['mappingType']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> type de mapping</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['mappingSystem']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> système de mapping</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['entityType']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> type d'entité</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['relationType']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> type de relation</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['propertyType']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> propriété</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['mappingContext']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> contextes de mapping</a></li>         
                <li *ngIf="admin" class="element"><a [routerLink]="['users']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> gestion des utilisateurs</a></li>
                <li class="element"><a [routerLink]="['version']"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-right "></i> gestion de versions</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is the code for my component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';
declare var $: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'side-menu',
    templateUrl: './side-menu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./side-menu.component.css']
})
export class sideMenuComponent {
    admin : boolean = false;
    edit : boolean = true;
    ngOnInit(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('role')=="ROLE_ADMIN"){
            this.admin = true;
        }
        if(localStorage.getItem('role')=="ROLE_VIEW"){
            this.edit = false;
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        $(document).on('click', '.element', function (e) {
            $('.element.activ').toggleClass('activ');
            $(this).toggleClass('activ');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.sidebar-nav li a', function (e) {
            $('.element.activ').toggleClass('activ');
        });

        $(document).on('click', ':not(.sidebar-nav li.open a)', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
/* remove if classe is active */
        $('.nav a').on('click', function () {
            $('.nav').find('.activ').removeClass('activ');
        });
    }
}
```

and here is my css code:

```
  /*.woll {
    margin-bottom: -21px;
}

.ssilka a{
    color:#0080C0;
}

.ssilka a:hover{
    color:#0080C0;
}

.list-group-item:last-child {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.list-group-item:first-child{
    border-radius: 0;
}
.side-menu{
    width: 20%;
}*/
#sidebar-wrapper { 
  -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  width: 180pt;
  left: 180pt;
  margin-left: -180pt;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  z-index:-5;
}
#sidebar-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.toggled{
    left:0;
}

.nav .open > a { background-color: transparent; }

.nav .open > a:hover { background-color: transparent; }

.nav .open > a:focus { background-color: transparent; }

.sidebar-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70pt;
  width: 180pt;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 14pt;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before {
  -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  width: 3pt;
  z-index: -1;
}

/*.sidebar-nav li:first-child a {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #ffffff;
}*/

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1).activ { background-color: #F55000; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(2).activ { background-color: #F6590D; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(3).activ  { background-color: #F7621A; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(4).activ  { background-color: #F86B27; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(5).activ  { background-color: #F97435; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(6).activ  { background-color: #FA7D42; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(7).activ  { background-color: #FB864F; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(8).activ  { background-color: #FC8F5D; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(9).activ  { background-color: #FD986A; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(10).activ  { background-color: #FEA177; }

.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(11):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(11).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(11).activ  { background-color: #FFAB85; }

.sidebar-nav li:hover:before {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #dddddd;
  display: block;
  padding: 7pt 10pt 7pt 20pt;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li.open:hover before {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu li a{
  margin-left: 10pt;
}

.sidebar-nav li.open a, .sidebar-nav li a:hover, .sidebar-nav li a:active, .sidebar-nav li a:focus, .sidebar-nav li.open a:hover, .sidebar-nav li.open a:active, .sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  font-size: 14pt;
  height: 52pt;
  line-height: 30pt;
}

.caret{
    float: right;
}
```

The problem is that this code does not work on the import and export button and I really do not know where it is the error!

I look forward to your response! your help would be really useful, and sorry if my question is stupid but I'm still just a beginner on this framework.

And thank you in advance for your response!

Comment: Have you tried using `!important`? There could be CSS libraries that you are using that are overwriting your color statement. By using `!important` you are specifying that the CSS line you put it on is of the highest importance and should not be overwritten by anything else. More information can be found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-important-in-css/
i.e.
`.sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1):before, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1).open, .sidebar-nav li:nth-child(1).activ { background-color: #F55000 !important; }`

Comment: Jquery in Angular!? ***Staawp Now*** And then, use the state stuff built in...

Comment: AngularJS and Angular are two different frameworks. Please update your tags with just the relevant one.

Comment: hello, i used the !important but it still didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, there are sooo many ways to do this. Basically, it's just state control.

For this example, I'm using a property in the class, but you could also use a property on an object or any other thing (like returning a class from a function).

## Don't Use JQuery

JQuery **was** great, but in Angular, just don't do it. Angular provides better ways to update the DOM without re-writing everything Angular does OoTB.

You can see the example [in Action here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dlgigw)

But the important parts:

```
<button type="button" [ngClass]="{'blue-button' : isBlue }" (click)='toggleButtonClass()'>Click Me</button>
```

A Button with a click event, and a class based on the state of a boolean value.

A little CSS for the button:

```
.blue-button {
 background-color:blue;
 color:white;
 }
```

And finally the function for toggling the class:

```
public toggleButtonClass(){
   this.isBlue = !this.isBlue;
}
```

Additionally, you could have an array of "Button" objects like:

```
export class Button implements IButton {
Text: string;
Value: string;
IsSelected?: boolean = false;
}
```

And then generate controls that do the same thing:

```
<div *ngFor="let button of Buttons">
   <button type="button" 
      (click)="toggleSelectedButton(button)" 
      [ngClass]="{'blue-button' : button.IsSelected}">{{button.Text}}
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: but is my code not correct? because on the others button it works well, it's just the export and import button that does not work, I probably forgot to put a few things or a little error that escapes me.

can't you help me solve my problem through my code please?

Comment: @Nawfalbougrine honestly, I say JQuery and just thought: "This is so bad, scrap it". That said, you are also using routing for the links on the sidebar? You could use ngClass based off of the current route as well... Really anything to dump JQuery today would be better than using your code...

Comment: I tested your code but it does not work here is what I did:at the level of my html I put:<li * ngIf = "edit" class = "element" id = "import"> <a [ngClass] = "{'orange-button': isOrange}" (click) = 'toggleButtonClass ()' [routerLink] = " ['import'] "> <i class =" fa fa-fw fa-arrow-alt-circle-up "> </i> import </a> </li> and at the level of my .ts I put:public isOrange = false;public toggleButtonClass () {this.isOrange =! this.isOrange;}and at the level of my css I put:.orange-button {background-color: #FFAB85;color: white;}but it does not work I still have the same error as what to do please?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use `HostListener` and `HostBinding`, so you create a directive that changes the color on click for example, and then you reuse it anywhere you want.

Please take a look at this example

```
  @Directive({
  selector: `[appHighlight]`
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  handleClick(event: Event) {
    if (this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.highlight('yellow');
    } else {
      this.highlight(null);
    }
  }

  highlight(color) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'backgroundColor', color);
  }
}
```

and then in html

```
<div>
  <p appHighlight>
    <span>Text to be highlighted</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

you can find a working example on [this page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwari1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: but is my code not correct? because on the others button it works well, it's just the export and import button that does not work, I probably forgot to put a few things or a little error that escapes me.

can't you help me solve my problem through my code please?